# How to synchronously access webbrowser.navigate

Tags: c#, winforms

How to get the html after navigating from webbrowser like as below in the code. This a dll library that can be used in other projects and it is not a winforms. After calling navigate it does not wait.

```
public List<Category> Categories;
public WebBrowser Browser;

public List<Category> ListAllCategories()
{
    Browser.DocumentCompleted += ReadAllCategories;
    Browser.Navigate(CoursesLink);
    //want to wait here until categories are built in the ReadAllCategories method without wasting CPU cycles
    return Categories;
}

void ReadAllCategories(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowser browser = sender as WebBrowser;
    switch (browser.ReadyState)
    {
        case WebBrowserReadyState.Complete:
            if (browser.Document != null)
            {
                //buildingListofCategories
            }
            break;
        case WebBrowserReadyState.Interactive:
            break;
        case WebBrowserReadyState.Loaded:
            break;
        case WebBrowserReadyState.Loading:
            break;
        case WebBrowserReadyState.Uninitialized:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    browser.DocumentCompleted -= ReadAllCategories;
}
```

Comment: You need to use `async` and build your own `Task`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple ways to support this.  One way is to simply encapsulate the asynchronous operation in one method using synchronization primitives to block the thread until the operation is completed asynchronously (**Warning: not tested**):

```
public List<Category> GetAllCategories(Uri CoursesLink)
{
    List<Category> categories = new List<Category>();
    ManualResetEventSlim waitEvent;
    using (WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser())
    {
        waitEvent = new ManualResetEventSlim();
        browser.DocumentCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            switch (browser.ReadyState)
            {
                case WebBrowserReadyState.Complete:
                    // TODO: your processing, filling categories
                    waitEvent.Set();
                    break;
                // TODO: error processing
            }
        };
        browser.Navigate(CoursesLink);
    }
    waitEvent.Wait(); // TODO: timeout?
    return categories;
}
```

The other, of course, is to use the built-in `Task` support in .NET to model the inherently asynchronous task in a `Task` object (similar to what Schabse mentioned) and simply call `Wait`  (**Warning: not tested**):

```
public Task<List<Category>> GetAllCategoriesAsync(Uri CoursesLink)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<List<Category>>();
    List<Category> categories = new List<Category>();
    using (WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser())
    {
        browser.DocumentCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            switch (browser.ReadyState)
            {
                case WebBrowserReadyState.Complete:
                    // TODO: your processing, filling categories
                    tcs.SetResult(categories);
                    break;
                    // TODO: error processing
            }
        };
        browser.Navigate(CoursesLink);
    }
    return tcs.Task;
}

//...

public List<Category> ListAllCategories()
{
    return GetAllCategoriesAsync(CoursesLink).Result;
}
```

I would recommend using the `Task`-based method as it better models the fact that what you have is an asynchronous operation and that you're actually *waiting* for it to complete.  In addition, you could then use it asynchronously in a UI:

```
var categories = await GetAllCategoriesAsync(CoursesLink);
```

Comment: No, that's just how I happened to do it.  I'll edit the answer to reflect that.

Comment: the ListAllCategories() method is of interface and has been marked as [OperationContract] attribute. So does this work same with that?

Comment: Sure `OperationContractAttribute` just makes a member of a class to correlate to an operation in a service contract in WCF.  You don't need to use await because you want it to be synchronous, so you don't need to decorate `ListAllCategories` with `async` so it shouldn't cause any problems--other than it could take a while and that you need to do error handling :).  I've updated my answer to show a `ListAllCategories` implementation.